# Enums in declaring functions

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble understanding the code below. I have no clue as to how to declare a function using enums (or maybe i'm understanding my assignment wrongly?) Think

```
int words_starting_with()
```

vs

```
enum Status words_starting_with()
```

Would appreciate if someone could give a quick explanation or direct me to more information.

(im not looking for written codes, just an explanation to help me complete my assignment would do)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to know how enums work? There's plenty of information about that out there.

Comment: I agree the question is abit convoluted, but essentially i'm asking what is the difference between the 2 types of function declaration ( int function() vs enum Status function() ). Hope this helps

Comment: Practically speaking there is not much of a difference, enum constants are usually represented by ints (although the compiler is free to use other integer types) and as opposed to C++, C lets you implicitly convert integers and enum constants to each other. The return type here mostly signals an _intent_, i.e. "this function is supposed to return Status enum constants".

Comment: I think this is pretty well-documented. Broadly, while an `enum` may be equivalent to an `int` internally, `enum` expresses the idea that only a specific set of values is appropriate. The compiler can perform some additional checks -- for example, if you do `switch(my_enum)` the compiler can warn if you haven't handled all the defined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are asked to fill a passed variable `num_word` and return the state of the function, is a common way to check errors:

```
enum Status {STATUS_OK, FILE_ERR_OPEN, NOT_FOUND};

enum Status words_starting_with(char const *dict, char letter, int *num_word)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(dict, "r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return FILE_ERR_OPEN;
    }

    char str[100];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, f))
    {
        if (*str == letter)
        {
            *num_word++;
        }
    }
    return *num_word == 0 ? NOT_FOUND : STATUS_OK;
}
```

As you can see, the `enum` is self-documenting the result of the function, now compare:

```
int num_word = 0;

switch (word_starting_with("dict.txt", 'a', &num_word))
{
    case FILE_ERR_OPEN:
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case NOT_FOUND:
        puts("dict doesn't contain words starting with 'a'");
        break;
    case STATUS_OK:
        printf("%d words starting with 'a'\n", *num_word);
        break;
}
```

with

```
int num_word = 0;

switch (word_starting_with("dict.txt", 'a', &num_word))
{
    case 1:
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 2:
        puts("dict doesn't contain words starting with 'a'");
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("%d words starting with 'a'\n", *num_word);
        break;
}
```

The first version is more clear and less prone to errors because you can even change the order of the constants in the `enum` and the result is still valid, also, as pointed out by @KeevinBoone in comments, the compiler can perform some additional checks:

```
switch (word_starting_with("dict.txt", 'a', &num_word))
{
    case FILE_ERR_OPEN:
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case STATUS_OK:
        printf("%d words starting with 'a'\n", *num_word);
        break;
}
```

raises

```
warning: enumeration value ‘NOT_FOUND’ not handled in switch
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, in fact it does what you were explicitly asked not to do: just solve the homework problem.

Comment: @Peter, for what I understand, it seems that OP doesn't know the benefits of using an `enum` (verbosity) vs `int`, and the homework is not solved yet, I have just provided a minimal compilable example.